# Have a posted song URL be an embedded music player with Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We would like our members to be able to share songs from our website and be able to listen to them inline a Facebook post.

SoundCloud is able to do this as seen in their posts on [their page here](https://www.facebook.com/soundcloud).

Are they doing this through being a *whitelisted member* and using [Open Graph Music](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/)?  If not, what would be the best way to accomplish that same player functionality?

It appears as though the player is not initiated within the Facebook post until the link is clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in that it's only for whitelisted members according to their documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/

> Facebook Open Graph Music is only available to whitelisted partners at
>   this time.

If it weren't for that requirement, you'd be able to achieve what you are asking by doing a Facebook Open Graph action with the Facebook approved requirements and parameters.