# Soundcloud player on own website as preview on Facebook Timeline (Open Graph)?

Tags: facebook, stream, facebook-opengraph, soundcloud

When posting Soundcloud links on Facebook, there is an interactive audio-player, possible because of the Open Graph API.
Is there any way I can embed a Soundcloud player on my page (using an iframe) and have the same player show up on Facebook when I post the link to my page?

E.g.
mypage.com/mynewalbum (contains iframe to soundcloud.com/user/mynewalbum)

So when posting this link on a Facebook-post (mypage.com/mynewalbum) I would like it to look like this with my URL:

[image]

Comment: Here is a similar discussion from 2013: [Have a posted song URL be an embedded music player with Facebook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922110/have-a-posted-song-url-be-an-embedded-music-player-with-facebook)